# How to use VBA/Excel to automate a data entry process using IE?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am extremely green with VBA, and am attempting to set up a macro sheet in Excel using VBA to partially automate a manual data entry process for my company to help cut down on time and error costs.

A successful script would accomplish the following:

1. Launch IE and navigate to the specified website.
2. Log in using provided credentials.
3. Enter a value into a field with a unique ID and press the "Next" button
4. Enter corresponding data into the 200 fields, each with unique ID's (Ex. LastName_0 would correspond to cell A2, LastName_1 Corresponds to A3, etc.)

Currently I have only accomplished step 1, in which the script launches IE and navigates to the website in question (https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/chrs/SignIn), however, I am getting a Run-time error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method) when attempting to insert the username and password for the site.

I've attempted multiple different codes that I found in google searches, all which return the same error. Currently I have the Username and Password listed on sheet 2 of the macro workbook, as referenced in the code. Given my lack of knowledge, I am unsure where my error exists.

For reference, we're running on VBA 7.1, Excel 2013, and IE 11.

```
Sub login()

    Const Url$ = "https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/chrs/SignIn"

    Dim UserName As String, Password As String, LoginData As Worksheet
    Set LoginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    UserName = LoginData.Cells(1, "B").Value
    Password = LoginData.Cells(2, "B").Value

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie

        .navigate Url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = True

        Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
        Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("txtUserName")(0) 
{This is where the 438 error occurs ^}
        Set oPassword = .document.getElementsByName("pwPassword")(0)

        oLogin.Value = UserName
        oPassword.Value = Password
        .document.forms(0).submit

    End With

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Currently, Sheet 2 is set up with the user ID in cell B1, and the Password in Cell B2.

The expected results would be a successful login, at which point I would work towards figuring out the code for the page to follow, and for the actual data entry page.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper page load wait. Use ids as well as they are faster. I use css id selectors e.g. `#txtUserName`, which are equivalent to `getElementById` but faster.

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub Login()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Const URL As String = "https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/chrs/SignIn"
    Dim userName As String, password As String, loginData As Worksheet

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    Set loginData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    userName = loginData.Cells(1, "B").Value
    password = loginData.Cells(2, "B").Value

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#txtUserName").Value = userName
            .querySelector("#pwPassword").Value = password
            .querySelector("#btnSubmit").Click
        End With

        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```